# Overflow scroll issue for iFrame in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, firefox

I have an **iFrame** here with `overflow:scroll` on CSS. It works perfectly in Firefox and it doesn't work in Chrome! Any idea why is this happening? Live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/fmCTD/). You can test it in Firefox then in Chrome and you will see the issue! Thank you for your time!

Comment: 1. Your jsFiddle doesn't show anything related 2. use lower case characters for HTML tags please 3. define `doesn't work`

Comment: My jsFiddle shows an iframe window that works in firefox and doesn't work in Chrome according to it's css style. Here is the link again http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/fmCTD/. Overflow scroll appears in Firefox but doesn't appear in Chrome! Thank you!

Comment: If anybody stumbles upon this, I've actually addressed this issue in the "share the knowledge" post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470015/html5-iframe-no-scrolling/18470016#18470016

Answer (score 1):

It's not displaying the scroll bars because there is no overflow - there is nothing to scroll.

```
<iframe id="scroll" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```

After giving scrollable content, the scroll bars appear: http://jsfiddle.net/fmCTD/4/

Comment: I think he's saying it doesn't work as in the scroll bars don't actually respond to feedback. Issue reproduced here.

Comment: The scrolling works fine. The reason scrolling didn't work with `http://jsfiddle.net` is because of its responsive layout. I've modified my answer to use `http://example.com` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/fmCTD/4/

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Please read my question again!!! Open my online example in firefox first then in chrome and you will see the difference... In firefox scrollbars are always on and in chrome aren't!!!

Comment: @GREENMADNESS That's a feature not a bug. Only show scroll bar when they're required. Good thing!

Comment: @GREENMADNESS: Your question states that Chrome is the problem, not Firefox. If you don't want the scrollbars to appear in Firefox simply remove the `overflow:scroll` - I'm not sure why you'd want to have scrollbars displaying with no scrollable content in the first place.

Comment: What I want is srollbars to be always on... It works in firefox it doesn't work in chrome! I don't think I am saying something so dificult to understand! Thank you!

Comment: @GREENMADNESS your question states simply that it's "not working in Chrome and it is in Firefox", nothing about what working means. Show some respect to the people who are answering your questions...

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with just an iframe alone as Chrome doesn't let you add scrollbars to an iframe using the `overflow` CSS attribute. This in theory shouldn't be allowed anyway for security reasons. I'm confused as to why you're wanting to display scrollbars when there is no scrollable content.

Comment: for modern browsers, they intend to **HIDE** scrollbars to simplify the user interface. Showing a non-scrollable scrollbar is meaningless.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: My friend, the point is how scrollbars showup in firefox using overflow sroll and doesn't showup in chrome?

Comment: @GREENMADNESS: My friend green, as you can understand, you wont get any answer here, cause everybody is trying to say what is better for browsers and stuff like that and not to give you a solution! By the way I have exactly the same problem and I haven't find any solution yet!

Comment: @GREENMADNESS if anything **Firefox's rendering of scrollbars through the `overflow` property is incorrect.** Chrome, Opera and even Internet Explorer do not display scrollbars in your example. I don't understand why you'd want to display scrollbars which have no purpose - despite saying this twice now, you still haven't given a reason why you actually want this as a desired effect. My answer here informs you of why the scroll bars are not present and goes on to give an example of how they appear only when required.

Comment: @GREENMADNESS it's also worth noting that no two browsers are identical. In an ideal world, Firefox and Chrome would both conform word for word to the HTML, CSS and JavaScript specifications, but this isn't the case.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: In to the site I am working on, whitch is still offline, this iframe is a modal window and it has content. For some reason, that I can't explain right now (I don't really have the time to do this) I need both scroll bars to be shown even if they don't need to be!!! It has to do with the shape of iframe window...

Comment: @GREENMADNESS the information you've provided to back up what you're asking makes absolutely no sense. Scrollbars are added *inside* an element, and shouldn't change the shape of anything. This is the first time you've mentioned a modal window and I don't think any of us here actually understand what you're trying to do. Why would you want scroll bars to appear if they aren't usable? Having scroll bars present just to retain shape of something is an illogical way of designing something.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Well my friend you know something? I don't really want to spend your time cause I know it is precious. Really thank you for your help and your time! I am close to find the answer, so when I have it, I will post it here for others who may have the same "problem".

Comment: @GREENMADNESS this is the problem though. I don't think this *problem* will actually affect anyone else as I don't think anyone else is aware of what the problem here actually is. You're asking for help but saying you can't give us any information because there isn't enough time? Adding scroll bars to retain some design is bad practice - especially as scroll bar widths and heights vary across different browsers anyway!). That's on par with adding `&nbsp;` for padding. Why don't you simply increase the width and/or height of your modal window to allow for a scroll bar if it's ever necessary?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: I have the same problem and I haven't find the solution yet!

Comment: @DNA180: For you then, *why* are you wanting non-functioning scroll bars present? Although I do get the feeling that you're either both the same person or both working on the same thing as each other going by your activity history...

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: We are not the same person but we are both working the same thing as you said!!!

Comment: @DNA180: well do you have more time available to actually discuss the issue you're both having? Although let me reiterate that there is really no reason non-functioning scroll bars should be present just for shaping purposes.

Comment: @DNA180: It's ok man, please...

@JamesDonnelly: Can you please take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/b9Pf3/3/) example and tell me how it is possible to work for `div` and not for `iframe`? Isn't an issue? Check it using Chrome please!

Comment: @GREENMADNESS: I've already told you above that Firefox is **incorrectly handling this**. The scroll bars *shouldn't* be present at all on the iframe. The `overflow` property shouldn't work at all on iframes as this would involve changing the iframe's source content - which is a security risk.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that's simply not true, overflow is the thing that should, in future, replace the **still working** attribute `scrolling` and is only a security risk if cross origin restrictions (and whitelisting) is not enforced/applied. And this was true in 2013 and sadly is still true in 2020 (Chrome still doesn't support overflow for iframe).