# HTML5 : Iframe No scrolling?

Tags: html, iframe, scroll

When it comes to HTML5, scrolling attribute is no longer supported - but I still need to remove the scroll bars - how to do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In HTML5 there is no scrolling attribute because "its function is better handled by CSS" see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/ for other changes. Well and the CSS solution:

**CSS solution:**

HTML4's `scrolling="no"` is kind of an alias of the CSS's `overflow: hidden`, to do so it is important to set size attributes width/height:

```css
iframe.noScrolling{
  width: 250px; /*or any other size*/
  height: 300px; /*or any other size*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add this class to your iframe and you're done:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" class="noScrolling"></iframe>
```

**! IMPORTANT NOTE ! :** `overflow: hidden` for `<iframe>` is not fully supported by all modern  browsers yet(even chrome doesn't support it yet) so for now (**2013**) it's still better to use ***Transitional*** version and use `scrolling="no"` and `overflow:hidden` at the same time :)

**UPDATE 2020:** the above is still true, oveflow for iframes is still not supported by all majors

Comment: Why not `iframe[scrolling='no'] { overflow: hidden; }`?

Comment: @mattcurtis Well since attribute selectors are supported since CSS2 - it is a solution too :) - **but remember** the scrolling="no" will be removed someday - therefore class is more perspective :)

Comment: However iframe[scrolling = "no"] will never be removed ;)

Comment: If you can, adding `html, body {overflow: hidden}` to the CSS of the document within the iframe also seems to work.

Comment: @daiscog of course, it is referencing almost the same thing :) But nice point.

Comment: Wouldn't `overflow: visible` do the same thing but make it so you don't have to define the height and width?

Comment: The usual point of "no scrolling" is to hide parts from the i-framed page you don't need... however you have an interesting idea, altough I don't think browsers will allow such a behaviour (security issue)... but who knows, with copy feature coming back, anything can happen :)

Comment: overflow still has no effects for iframe in fx and chrome in 2017

Comment: Still no effects for Chrome in 2019