# How to disable Horizontal Scroll Bar In iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have used iframe for view multiple image with in the frame and I want to hide the Horizontal Scroll Bar. I Have used following code snippet.

```
<div class="framepart">
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.puthuvannam.com/vendors/sample/documents/<?php echo $res['name'];?>&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;overflow-y:hidden;" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden" frameborder="0">          
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: use scrolling="no" attribute to resolve your problem. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_scrolling) also ...

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt The code snippet included _does_ contain that. As far as I can tell, it works fine and there is nothing to solve - http://jsfiddle.net/U8JCj/1/. All I changed from this code is the width (to prevent the JSFiddle window from horizontally scrolling.)

Comment: i have changed the link please try it now and let me know the soultion

Comment: http:// jsfiddle.net/U8JCj/2/ check this and let me know how to disable the scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem.

I changed the `src` of the `<iframe>` to `http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.google.com/&embedded=true` (http://jsfiddle.net/U8JCj/2/).

By inspecting this in Developer Tools, it can be seen that it is *not* the `<iframe>` that has an overflow, but the inner `<div id="content-pane">` which has `overflow: auto`. As this is internal to Google Docs, it is not a style you can change, and therefore there is no solution to this (while using Google Docs).

Comment: css file: .framepart{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
  
}

Comment: yes you have found the problem and i have updated my link in my  question and also update the css file in above comment so please let me know the solution how to disable that scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>

iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

`scrolling="no"` will work in IE10, Chrome 25 and Opera 12.12.

However the `<iframe>` scrolling attribute is not supported in HTML5, even though most browsers understand it.

See [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspoverflow.htm) article to learn more on scrolling.

Comment: you are right scrolling attribute will not work with HTML5. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470015/html5-iframe-no-scrolling)

Comment: It also says that browsers such as Chrome don't support only the CSS attribute.

Comment: hi check this http://www.puthuvannam.com/vendors/sample/index.php?id=7 I want to hide the scrollbar