# How to hide Horizontal scrollbar in Iframe tag?

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar

I have an iframe inside a div. I need to hide the horizontal scrolling bar.
I just need the vertical one activated.

HTML Code

```
<div id="rc">
    <div>
        <iframe class="defRC" src="url"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
</div>
```

I've added some CSS code but without success

```
.defRC {
   overflow-y: hidden;
   width: 1000px; 
   height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: include overflow-x:hidden;

Comment: try `overflow-x: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe scr="url" class="defRC" scrolling="no" />
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18470016/2277280

Comment: I just want for the horizontal scrollbar disabled and the vertical one enabled.

Comment: i guess this is only possible by changing overflow of the document referenced by the iframe, which is not always possible.

Comment: It could be possible if I know the resolution of the web page? :s and how can I get it?